# Kohana 3 ORM - grouping where conditions with parentheses

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm trying to run a query through the ORM like this:

```
   SELECT * from table where (fname like 'string%' or lname like 'string%') 
AND (fname like 'string2%' or lname like 'string2%');
```

Here's what i have so far:

```
$results = ORM::factory('profiles');
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $result->where('fname', 'like', "$string%");
    $result->or_where('lname', 'like', "$string%");
}
```

But this doesn't account for the parentheses.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you stumble upon this problem in Kohana 2, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56109498/3017716

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer.

It's done with Kohana's where_open() and where_close() methods.

Comment: Sorry DexterW, I inadvertently downvoted your answer and now it won't let me undo the downvote...

Answer (score 7):

It works fine for me .

ORM code sample

```
$musicslist = ORM::factory('user_music')
            ->where_open()
            ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->or_where('album', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->or_where('artist', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where_close()
            ->and_where('app_userid','=', $userid)
            ->find_all();
```

it will create SQL query

```
SELECT `user_musics`.* FROM `user_musics` WHERE (`title` LIKE '%as%' OR `album` LIKE '%as%' OR `artist` LIKE '%as%') AND `app_userid` = '21'
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get code formatting to work in the comment - just thought I'd add a simple example to the answer in case anyone else comes across it:

```
$query = DB::select()
           ->from('some_table')
           ->where_open()
           ->where('column_one', '=', 1)
           ->or_where('column_two', '=', 2)
           ->where_close();
```

would produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE (column_one = 1 OR column_two = 2);
```